# Deployment issue for custom app in spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

While deploying stream I am getting below error and deployment is failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception trying to list configuration properties for application jar:file:/C:/Users/atp1rzs/.m2/repository/net/atpco/rpc/route-path-cache-maintenance/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/route-path-cache-maintenance-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.listProperties(BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata-1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

## at

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while creating ClassLoader for jar:file:/C:/Users/atp1rzs/.m2/repository/net/atpco/rpc/route-path-cache-maintenance/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/route-path-cache-maintenance-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.BootClassLoaderFactory$ClassLoaderExposingLauncher.createClassLoader(BootClassLoaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata-1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

Comment: This doesn't include the entire stacktrace - it is hard to relate to the root-cause of the exception. It might be useful if you can attach a file with all the details.

Comment: Please also include as many details as possible when reporting problems - follow this [wiki-link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/wiki/Reporting-Issues).